# How does a driving voltage affect an LC circuit?

Tags: inductor, oscillator, phasor

[image: Circuit]

I need help understanding how the drive voltage \$V_d\$ and the coupling capacitor \$C_d\$  in the circuit above affect the total energy of the LC circuit.

The author arrives at the following equation to represent the driving Hamiltonian: \$H_d = \dfrac{1}{1+C/C_d}QV_d(t)\$ in their [paper](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/theses/Sank2014.pdf) (Eq D.16 Pg 190).

#### Questions

- What does \$Q\$ correspond to in this equation? Is that the total charge on the capacitor \$Q\$?
- If I'm understanding this correctly. Adding the drive voltage and drive capacitor to the circuit allows me to offset the LC circuit's energy by an amount that's \$\propto\$ \$QV_d(t)\$. This value oscillates between +ve and -ve values and this means that the LC circuit's energy will keep oscillating as well with an offset of \$\dfrac{1}{1+C/C_d}QV_d(t)\$ around its original value \$E_0\$. Is my understanding correct?
- If my previous assumption is correct. How is it possible that we can dynamically remove energy from the LC circuit? Qualitatively, how can we add voltage/power and somehow this would result in decreasing energy?

Comment: Suppose a person is on a swing, and as they are swinging down toward the bottom, you push against them to slow them down. You've just removed energy by "driving" the system.

Comment: @DanielSank this is a helpful analogy. I understand now that the energy can increase/decrease depending on the relative direction of the current in the LC circuit and the driving current. But I'm thinking if I'm pushing a person swinging with some sinusoidal function (I think it has \$2\omega\$ frequency) that's leading by a quarter phase. I'd think that the time period between the maximum and minimum energy levels should be \$\propto \dfrac{1}{\omega}\$. But from Eq D.57, it seems like \$t \propto \dfrac{\sqrt{\hbar}}{\sqrt{\omega}}\$. Which I think is strange.